# How to read HTML in textarea?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, textarea

I would create field textarea, when user type html basic into textarea, result can read html.

Code basic

```
<form action="">
    Name:
    <input type="text">
    Contents:
    <textarea name="contents"></textarea>
</form>
```

I type `<strong>Hello World</strong>` into textarea, when submit result **Hello World**

This is like Widget Text in Wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to dynamically create html elements based on user input. Try using JQuery! Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/m7jba0uk/1/

HTML:

```
<form action="">
    Name:
    <input type="text"><br>
    Contents:
    <textarea name="contents"></textarea>
</form>
<input type='button' onclick='doTheThing()' value='Do the thing'>
<div id='result'></div>
```

JS:

```
function doTheThing() {
    $('#result').append($('textarea[name="contents"]').val());
}
```

Try typing in `<strong>Hello World</strong>`

I hope it helps implementing your idea.